# Translation of vibrational motion in the 15-20 Hz range

Tags: fluid-mechanics, vibration

Is anyone familiar with how to create a "shaking" fluidized bed. With vibrational amplitude in the 2" range and Hz 15-20?

I'm constructing a vibrational fluidized bed dryer for the purpose of drying shredded coconut. This machine, as far as I can tell, is generally a continuous process - however my team and I are trying to construct a batch type system.

We have two 1/2HP vibrating motors running of a VFD, mounted the the rigid frame at the center of the machine, which is attached to a series of 6 springs - 110 lb/in, 7n, 6" coils evenly spaced throughout the structure. We have had success translating the motion evenly in the 40-50Hz range to achieve a fluidized bed. But it's our understanding that the fluidization will be superior in a shaking system. However when we run tests the coconut consistently goes to a certain side, depending on the vibrational force settings and the exact Hz.

Is it possible to translate this motion to the purely vertical plane and keep this amplitude consistent while still using springs? Or is a different dampening mechanism needed.

(Note, there are also about 20 15 lb/in springs added evenley throughout the structure to stablilize vibrations, are these necessary?)

Thanks!

Comment: Realistically, it will be hard to not have some transport force is these systems. That is why shaker tables are often part of conveyor systems, where they shake out crumbs through a screen prior to scaling and packaging. You design the system to be in resonance with the springs, so you need to have the weight nearly constant. That is hard with a batch dryer. The frequency will change as the material dries. So you will need to track that frequency with the driver.

Comment: If you are drying coconut, you may want to consider a different damping mechanism rather than a dampening mechanism. The former restricts movement while the latter adds moisture.